# How do I remove related objects in linq to entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, foreign-key-relationship

I have 2 tables:

```
orders 
orderItems
```

connected to one another threw a relationship(FK `orderId` in the `orderItems` table). is there a difference between:

```
order.orderitems.remove(...)
```

to just setting the `orderId` value to `null` when trying to remove the related entity?

Comment: Hw90's answer is wrong. There is no difference between the two things you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the FK property to null and removing the entity from the navugation property both do the same thing. That is, they both sever the relationship between the entities but do not cause either entity to be deleted. It's the same as setting the FK value in the database to NULL.

To delete the entity you must call Remove on the DbSet for the entity. For example

```
context.OrderItems.Remove(orderitem);
context.SaveChanges();
```